# Children not setting layout_width/-height in custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, children, viewgroup

I made a custom ViewGroup which kinda works except that when I drag&drop views to this ViewGroup, editor says it cannot set layout_width and layout_height to children. What could be causing it?

I have overriden two methods only - onLayout and onMeasure. I believe I have made a mistake in my onMeasure as I don't yet understand how it's supposed to measure children.

Anyway, here is my onMeasure:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    final int childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    final int childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

    int count = getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);

        child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(mWidth, mHeight);
}
```

So, how do I let my viewgroup's children to acquire layout_with and layout_height parameters?

P.S. I know my ViewGroup is fixed width and height but that's how I want it.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I should have used MeasureSpec.EXACTLY. Didn't know it existed.

```
child.measure(MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | childWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | childHeight);
```

P.S. If anyone has a better commented answer - I will accept it as an answer. I would love to read some more information ;)